# Passing input parameter and retrieving List from .NET WCF service in android app

Tags: android, .net, wcf, rest

I'm trying to call a .NET WCF service from android application. The WCF Restful service method takes in a string param and returns a List.

The WCF service method is defined as -

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetAssignedSiteInfo")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetAssignedSiteInfo?user={user}")]
    List<SiteData> GetAssignedSiteInfo(string user);
```

The android app code is as follows -

```
public ArrayList<Parent> FromJSONtoAssignedSitesArrayList(String userId) 
{
    final ArrayList<Parent> list = new ArrayList<Parent>();

    try  
    {
        //String http = Constants.AGENT_SERVICE_URI + "GetAssignedSiteInfo";
        String urlFinal = "http://10.0.2.2/SiteDataProvider/SiteDataService.svc/" + "GetAssignedSiteInfo" + "?user=";

        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(urlFinal.trim() + "" + URLEncoder.encode(userId,"UTF-8"));
        postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpClient hc = new AndroidHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        final String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);           
      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
return list;
}
```

Even though the url is set to use address 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost (wcf is hosted in iis on local machine), when the HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod); is called, an exception is thrown which says that 127.0.0.1/SiteDataProvider/SiteDataService.svc is not accessible. Connection refused:127.0.0.1

What is the problem? How are we supposed to call .NET WCF from android for this kind of functionality. Please guide.. I am struggling to get past this since almost a week now.

Comment: Is the WCF method used anywhere else? To me it seems like a GET method, not a POST. Can you try changing it to GET?

Comment: Also try the actual IP of the hosting machine.

Comment: @SKall - I am writing both the WCF and anroid app to work with each and the WCF is not being used anywhere else. I tried using the WCF test client to see, if the wcf could have any issues, but being a RESTful service, test client, doesn't even show its methods.   Also meaning put the actual IP address, if I do a IpConfig on my machine, which IP address do I use?

Comment: @SKall - Knowing there could be issue with the WCF which I somehow cannot verify with the WCF test client, what change to the WCF method do you suggest to make it POST and be able to pass string input param and return back List<Object> from the WCF method call?